Preserving EEPROM-Emulation area when programming new code - STM32 - VScode - JLink
I'm using the last flash page (page 31: 0x0800 F800 - 0x0800 FFFF2) as eeprom emulation area on my STM32G030C8.
I'm working with VScode and programming/debugging the flash with JLink over USB.
Is there a way to prevent the eeprom emulation area from being erased when programming new code, as there is stored some calibration data?

simply do not erase the whole chip :)

(1) Modify the linker script 'STM32G030C8Tx_FLASH.ld' and add the EE emulation area
    MEMORY
    {
    RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 8K
    FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 62K
    EMULATED_EEPROM    (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x0800F800,   LENGTH = 2K
    }

    /* Define output sections */
    SECTIONS
    {
        /* The startup code into "FLASH" Rom type memory */
      .ourData :
      {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.ourData)
        . = ALIGN(4);
      } >EMULATED_EEPROM
.
.
.

(2) Change linker script name (to e.g. STM32G030C8Tx_EE_FLASH.ld) for MXCube not to erase it when updating code
(3) Modify linker script path in 'CMakeLists.txt' like this
# Set linker script
set(linker_script_SRC   ${PROJ_PATH}/STM32G030C8Tx_EE_FLASH.ld)
set(EXECUTABLE          ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})

I've been reading out the memory areas and it seems to work fine.
If there is anything wrong or to improve, please give some feedback.
